# Sorting as association before saving using callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently migrated from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and in the process I noticed that sorting association does not work in Rails 4. Following are the sample models:

```
#box.rb

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :allow_destroy => true

  before_validate
    items.sort! { <some condition> } 
  end
end

#item.rb

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
end
```

In Rails 3, `sort!` method on the association modified the `items` hash, but in Rails 4 it returns a new sorted instance but does not modify the actual instance. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: more importantly, why are you doing this?

Comment: I get a list of items from the client which I need to sort before saving. I thought there should be a way to sort the associations before saving using a parameter before saving. In addition to that I need to validate the sorted association. The later is possible without the need to modify the association in place but the former is not.

Comment: There's no intrinsic value in "sorting" an association before saving. The order in which items are saved to the database shouldn't be part of your business logic, because it is not dependable in most DBMSs Ordering of collections should be handled when the collection is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#box.rb

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :allow_destroy => true

  before_validate
    self.items = items.sort { <some condition> } 
  end
end

#item.rb

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Comment: I tried this already. When I try to create a box with items using build method, the sorting does not work.

Comment: The only hack that is working right now is to use clear method to clear the association and then assign back sorted hash.

Comment: Moreover doing this fails all calls to update_attributes method with the exception can't modify frozen hash.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting before storing won't really help. When you pull them from the database they might not be in that order. You wan't to specify the order on the has many (or in the item model).

If you have a more complicated ordering, then please post that logic.

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Can replace position with hash like: { name: :asc }
  has_many :item, -> { order(:position) }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :allow_destroy => true

  before_validate
    items.sort! { <some condition> } 
  end
end
```